# relative import in multiple python files

Tags: python, django

I have the following directory structure:

The directory name is `test_app`

```
|-- __init__.py
|-- manage.py
|-- models.py
|-- views.py
```

I have a very basic question to ask, i place the following values inside my `__init__.py`

```
alpha = "123"
beta = "546"
```

How do i get the value of alpha and beta inside models, views and manage?
i tried the following:

```
from . import alpha

from test_app import alpha
```

both of them did not work, how do i do it?

Comment: have you added '.' to your pythonpath?

Comment: Both should work. I'm actually using `from app_name import some_var` myself in one of my project's apps. Not sure why it's not working for you. What error, if any, do you get?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`__init__.py` is usually empty and indicates that files in your directory, in this case test_app can be imported.  You could put your values in another .py file (example: constants.py) and do the following:

```
|-- __init__.py
|-- manage.py
|-- models.py
|-- views.py
|-- constants.py
```

Then import your constants:

```
from test_app import constants
```

The contents of constants.py would be

```
alpha = "123"
beta = "546"
```

Then you would be able to use what ever values you stored in constants

```
print(constants.alpha)
print(constants.beta)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I'd put constants, or things I needed to include, in `__init__.py`, but this:

```
from __init__ import things
```

Will work fine for importing `things` defined in `__init__.py`.

The reason I wouldn't do this is that often python packages use `__init__.py` to control what is exported via `from package.name import *` In this case, your constants would also be exported - which is fine if that's what you want, but bad if not.

Comment: is there a way of putting global variables on the folder scale, i mean say i put a value and that is available for all the files, in my case i was having a trouble that imports should be sequential, the above was a simplified version of what i was doing. So for me, the requirement is few variables that are accessible the same way from different files. is there a way out?

Comment: @user993563 yep - the answer you had above suggests declaring a file, `consts.py`, for the purpose - which is perfectly acceptable. Actually, you could put them in one of your existing files and just import them from the others.